CPU too slow after waking up in Ubuntu 24.04.1
I have AMD 7940hs pro, ubuntu 24.04.1, kernel 6.8.0.48 (and tested many other mainline kernels, the issue is always there). I have many issues, but the most serious one is the CPU sometime times (not always, say 50% of the times) wakes up with it's 10% maximum speed. This caused lag and I cannot resolve it without rebooting the computer.
Ubuntu (both 22.04 and 24.04) gives me a lot of issues with this "newer" hardware (although it is almost 2 years old!). I wish I could use the mac OS so that this nonsense ends here.

Perhaps the AMD pstate driver might help: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=292940

I can see similar issue - after waking from hibernation (though not always, but at least once a week) processes consume a lot more cpu. I can restart applications, but it doesn't help. Restart of the machine works and cpu consumption goes down to standard level. Smells like wake from hibernation bug.
My CPU is AMD Ryzen™ 7 PRO 7840HS w/ Radeon™ 780M Graphics × 16
I was trying to look at link from comment above and area seems too complex for me. Will try to change power mode from balanced to performance - balanced mode is not available in powermode-gui app for some reason

I tried to change power mode in Ubuntu config (and restarted few times) and I didn't get good cpu consumption without "balanced mode" settings. Others were just not working... I suppose I should use performance profiler mentioned somewhere in the link in first comment and create a bug...

I think the problem is much deeper, and can't be solved by power profile. I face this in performance mode as well. Do you also get visual artifacts while on igpu?

when I issue command to monitor cpu frequency "lscpu -e=CPU,MHZ" I can see that when issue occurs, cpus can't get above 600Mhz - otherwise there is 3500 or more on some cores.
The guy (with same computer) who suggested that command also said that he is not restarting computer when this occurs, he just plugs out power cable and then he plugs it in. Will try that when this occurs next time.

Exactly! That's what I am talking about. Please let me know if you find a trick to restore the full potential of the cpus in such cases without rebooting. I am wondering why this problem is not reported widely. I think this issue only appears for the amd gen 4 cpus, which is not even that new! Such a shame, after spending so much! I am never going with amd ever again. That's why people use mac which is unfortunately not my cup of tea.

plug out power cable and plug in cable this morning helped.

I have created https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2088733

Yes, your trick works as of now! Thank you, life saver! I have one more question: when using the igpu (780M) consistently see artifacts and screen flickering. Do you also see these ?

Well, someone else told me to try plug out and plug in the cable :-)
I don't see screen artifacts or flickering.

Thanks. Now I am worried. I have this screen artifacts with the same igpu 780m! However, there is no issue on windows! I am tired of linux now.
